# Запись данных из GET-запроса в XML файл

Tags: xml, php, dom, get

Ребят, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
Мне надо научиться сохранять переменные из GET-запроса в XML файл.
Что я имею:

```
<?php
$u_id = $_GET["uid"];
$f_name = $_GET["first_name"];
$l_name = $_GET["last_name"];
$foto = $_GET["photo"];
$m_foto = $_GET["photo_rec"];
$hash = $_GET["hash"];

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');

$root = $doc->createElement('info');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$user_id = $doc->createElement('user_id', $u_id);
$user_id = $root->appendChild($user_id);

$fname = $doc->createElement('fname', $f_name);
$fname = $root->appendChild($fname);

$lname = $doc->createElement('lname', $l_name);
$lname = $root->appendChild($lname);

$url_photo = $doc->createElement('url_photo', $foto);
$url_photo = $root->appendChild($url_photo);

$url_photo_m = $doc->createElement('url_photo_m', $m_foto);
$url_photo_m = $root->appendChild($url_photo_m);

$user_hash = $doc->createElement('user_hash', $hash);
$user_hash = $root->appendChild($user_hash);

$doc->save("req.xml");
?>
```

это содержимое файла index.php, обращаясь к нему с GET-запросом

```
index.php?
uid=1
&first_name=xxx
&last_name=yyy
&photo=http://qqq/qqq.jpg
&photo_rec=http://www/www.jpg
&hash=hhh
```

не получаю ожидаемого результата, то есть в файле req.xml не изменяется содержимое.
А почему? Или может есть какой другой действенный способ? А может дело в веб-сервере?(пользую сервер ho.ua)

Comment: А то, что вы малую стрелку не указали в нескольких случаях - это опечатка? Например, эта строка:

    $user_id = $root- appendChild($user_id);
    // должна быть написана так:
    $user_id = $root->appendChild($user_id);

Упс... ))) А вот это что такое? ))) 

    $u_id = "$_GET[uid]";

Правильно так:

    $u_id = $_GET["uid"];

Comment: Исправил, не помогает...

Comment: @Владимир Archi, данные точно приходят GET-запросом? Проверьте - выведите на экран.

Comment: Посмотрите есть ли разрешение на запись в эту папку еще

Comment: И на запись в файл есть ли разрешение

Comment: Deonis, а как ещё, если не GET-запросом в адресной строке будет виден набор передаваемых данных?

igolka97, разрешения на запись имеются.

Проблема решена!
нужно было только удалить строку кодировки из конструктора ДомДокумента...

Comment: @Владимир Archi, я ваш уровень не знаю, а элементарных ошибок тут уже насмотрелся. Поэтому не удивился, если  бы данные передавались из формы методом POST, а принимались бы GET. В общем, советую включить режим STRICT и посмотреть какие "бока" вылезут.

P.S. Только что проверил ваш код - работает без проблем.

Comment: Deonis, действительно работает с абстрактными данными в запросе.
Проблема оказалась в кодировке.
Осталось только перекодировать значения $f_name и $l_name, а то русские символы отображаются не корректно. И еще, в адресной строке значение first_name=%C2%EB%E0%E4%E8%EC%E8%F0, в файл записывается <fname>&#xAB;&#x928;&#xCA30;</fname>, а на странице сайта отображается fname=В«а¤ЁмЁ° 
осталось понять в какую сторону декодировать

Comment: @Владимир Archi, У вас все документы в одной кодировке? И хотелось бы надеятся, что все в utf-8? ))

Comment: ну наверное... если верить описаниям... :)))